# Signup with email verification in Meteor not working? How should it be done?

Tags: email, meteor, mandrill, email-verification

I'm trying to create my custom sign up page with email verification in Meteor. I want to use Mandrill for sending the verification email. In the **server** folder, I've a method-

```
addUser: function(user) {
    console.log("Adding User - ", user);
    var userOptions = {
        email: user.email, password: user.password,
        profile: {firstname: user.firstname, lastname: user.lastname}
    };

    var createdUser = Accounts.createUser(userOptions);
    console.log("CreatedUser-", createdUser);
    Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, createdUser) {
        if (options.profile) {
            createdUser.profile = options.profile;
        }
        else {
            createdUser.profile = {};
        }
        Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(createdUser._id, createdUser.email);
        return createdUser;
    });
```

The *Accounts.createUser* method is inserting a record, but the emails are not going out. I've also defined the process.env.MAIL_URL with the Mandrill smtp credentials. I'm tired looking through the docs and checked a couple of blogs but nothing seems to work. If I remove *createUser()* then the user is not inserted in mongo db and *onCreateUser()* fails with exception. I've gone through the Meteor documents, but still confused about, how *onCreateUser()* works? How will the *onCreateUser()* method will get the options and user parameters? I've been stuck with this, any guidance/help is appreciated. After going through another question on stackoverflow, I removed the email pacakge. I do have *wylio:mandrill* added to the project. Do I need the email package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to set a config setting like so:

```
Accounts.config({
  sendVerificationEmail: true
});
```

If this isn't set to true (and it's false by default), it will output the content of the email into the server console, which is good for testing, but bad for actually sending out emails obviously.

I'd add the email package back in, I think you need that to send out emails. Hope that helps.

Comment: I had already set the **sendVerificationEmail** to true. I had to add the email package back. Thanks for that. But still it wasn't working so, I tried it with another smtp server, like gmail.

Answer (score 0):

To send the email I added the gmail smtp on the server side. Will look into mandrill later on, once I build some momemtum.

```
var smtp = {
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: "465",
    username: "<your gmail id without @gmail.com>",
    password: "<your password>",
    //ssl: true
};
```

I created a separate account on gmail for this. For adding the user, I had to change the code. I first created the user with Accounts.createUser() on the client end and then invoked a method to send email having Accounts.sendVerificationEmail() on the server side js.

```
//client-side
var createdUserId = Accounts.createUser(userOptions, function(error) {
                console.log(error);
}); 
Meteor.call('registerUser', createdUserId);

//Server-side
registerUser: function(createdUserId) {
....
    Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(createdUser._id);
....
}
```